# Alternative for _Unwind_Find_FDE for high frequency callstack generation

Tags: c++, linux

I have to debug a multithreaded C++ app on Linux that generates callstacks with high frequency for tracing purposes and is very slow. The bulk of the computing effort seems to be the _Unwind_Find_FDE function which resolves the symbols at every call and locks a global mutex every time, causing lock contention and increased futex system calls.

Do you know a C++ based backtrace function that determines at least the shared objects of the virtual address and does not have these problems? Otherwise, my first guess would be to use the standard backtrace function (this one should be lock-free, right?) and track the virtual memory mappings in a way that does not use dl_iterate_phdr.

Btw should the _Unwind_Find_FDE function even lock that mutex in modern implementations when the virtual memory layout doesn't change?

Can you give me a recommendation for a function or general approach?

Regards.